# How to download very large files (~50 GB) from FTP Server using ftpwebrequest in C#

Tags: c#, ftp, chunks, ftpwebrequest

I've tried downloading file from FTP server in chunks using the `FtpWebRequest` and merging the chunks to original file. The process works fine for 4GB or lower files but when trying the same process for 8 or 9GB files I'm getting an error

Here is the error I'm getting

[image]

Here is the sample code I've worked out

```
private static long limitSize = Convert.ToInt64(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LimitSize"]);

public static void DownloadFromFTP()
    {
        var guid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

        var path = $"{System.Environment.CurrentDirectory}/UploadedFiles/{guid}";

        try
        {

            string strFilePath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FilePath"];
            NetworkCredential credentials = new NetworkCredential(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UserName"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Password"]);
            Console.WriteLine("Starting...");
            string name = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FileName"];
            var strFolderPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Key"] + name;
            FtpWebRequest sizeRequest = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(strFilePath);
            sizeRequest.KeepAlive = false;
            sizeRequest.Credentials = credentials;
            sizeRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.GetFileSize;
            long size = sizeRequest.GetResponse().ContentLength;
            Console.WriteLine($"File has {size} bytes");

            double filesizecheck = Convert.ToDouble(size) / Convert.ToDouble(limitSize);
            int chunks = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Ceiling(filesizecheck));
            long chunkLength = size / chunks;

            List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();


            if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(path))
            {
                System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
            }
            var filepath = $"{path}/{name}";


            for (int chunk = 0; chunk < chunks; chunk++)
            {
                int i = chunk;
                tasks.Add(Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    try
                    {
                        FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(strFilePath);
                        request.Credentials = credentials;
                        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;
                        request.UseBinary = true;
                        request.UsePassive = true;
                        request.KeepAlive = false;
                        request.ContentOffset = chunkLength * i;
                        long toread =
                            (i < chunks - 1) ? chunkLength : size - request.ContentOffset;
                        Console.WriteLine(
                            $"Downloading chunk {i + 1}/{chunks} with {toread} bytes ...");

                        using (Stream ftpStream = request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
                        using (Stream fileStream = File.Create(filepath + "." + i))
                        {
                            var bufferSize = Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BufferSize"]);
                            byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
                            int read;
                            while (((read = (int)Math.Min(buffer.Length, toread)) > 0) &&
                                   ((read = ftpStream.Read(buffer, 0, read)) > 0))
                            {
                                fileStream.Write(buffer, 0, read);
                                toread -= read;
                            }
                        }
                        Console.WriteLine($"Downloaded chunk {i + 1}/{chunks}");
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"Exception: {ex}");
                        Console.ReadKey();
                    }
                }));
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Started all chunks downloads, waiting for them to complete...");
            Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
            CombineMultipleFilesIntoSingleFile(path, filepath);

            var result = UploadToS3(filepath, strFolderPath, size, path).Result;

            Console.WriteLine("Done");
            Console.ReadKey();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception " + ex.Message);
            DeleteFiles(path);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Here is the method to merge the files

```
private static void CombineMultipleFilesIntoSingleFile(string inputDirectoryPath, string outputFilePath)
    {
        string[] inputFilePaths = Directory.GetFiles(inputDirectoryPath);
        Console.WriteLine("Number of files: {0}.", inputFilePaths.Length);
        using (var outputStream = File.Create(outputFilePath))
        {
            foreach (var inputFilePath in inputFilePaths)
            {
                using (var inputStream = File.OpenRead(inputFilePath))
                {
                    // Buffer size can be passed as the second argument.
                    inputStream.CopyTo(outputStream);
                }
                Console.WriteLine("The file {0} has been processed.", inputFilePath);
            }
        }
    }
```

App Config settings

```
    <add key="LimitSize" value="10000000"/>
    <add key="BufferSize" value="10240"/>
```

Comment: Please share the error details as well. If you fail exactly at 4GB, worth seeing if you're writing to a FAT32 partition/USB drive.

Comment: @Madushan Thank you for the quick response. I've added the error image.

Comment: The connection closed according to the error message.  You need to determine which end of the connection initiated the closing.  I would use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and see which end of the connection intiated the [FIN].  More likely the server end in this case stopped.

Comment: Is it always the same chunk, where it fails? Can you download that specific chunk on its own? + Your 4GB vs 8 or 9GB info is incomplete. Where's the boundary? Is there an exact boundary at all?  + Can you download a complete file using any commandline/GUI FTP client? + Show us a full exception callstack. + Why are you setting `request.KeepAlive = false`?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl No, its not the same chunk that always fails. The FTP server I'm using to download files has only 2 files which are greater than 4GB and the rest are 4GB or less. So, I've  tried downloading both the files and the last set of chunk files are not being downloaded for some reason. I'm trying to download the file using FileZilla client but it's showing almost 5-6 hours to download the file. request.keepalive is set to false to close the ftp server connection after the web request finishes.

Comment: Edit all that into your question. Do not post any information into comments. + You didn't post the callstack + At what stage of the last chunk download do you get the error? Do you get the error even if you download the last chunk only? Do you get the error if you use `ftpStream.CopyTo(fileStream)` instead of your `while` loop?  => We need [mcve] +  *"request.keepalive is set to false to close the ftp server connection after the web request finishes"*: What for?!?